# How to speed up Pig MultiStorage

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I'm using Pig's MultiStorage to split an input file into lots of smaller output files.

If it helps, the script looks something like:

```
<snip registers and defines>
a = load '$FILES' using AvroStorage();
a_projected = foreach a generate field1, field2;
a_explode = foreach a_projected generate field1, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(field2));

--splitting based on field2
store a_explode into '$OUTPUT' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('$OUTPUT','1');
```

This is reading from and writing to S3.  The '$FILES' parameter tends to be a single folder with one file of around 10,000 lines, approximately 2 MB in size.

When using MultiStorage, this splits into on the order of around 4-5 thousand separate folders with one file in them, and takes approximately 15 minutes to run.

When using PigStorage, I get one output file, as expected, and it takes about 20 seconds to run.

Is that kind of performance to be expected from MultiStorage? Is there anything that can be done to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You key space might be too wide - MultiStorage in which case will end up creating several files, one for each key. Creating too many files (internally MultiStorage creates a Writer for each key) takes a huge amount of time. If you do not wish to have a file per key, you should just use PigStorage.